# one controller for multiple pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i maked one website with routes by $routeProvider, i made controller for every page and it looks like:

```html
   myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
         
         .when('/category/Web development', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/web-dev.html',
            controller: 'catCtrl'
        })
         .when('/category/Game Programming', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/game-programming.html',
            controller: 'catCtrl2'
        })
     
     myApp.controller('catCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/web-dev")
         .then(function (response) {
            $scope.books = response.data;
     });
 $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/category" )
     .then(function (response) {
         $scope.categories = response.data;
     });
     $scope.login = false;
     $scope.hideLogin = true;
     $scope.showLoginDiv = function() {
        $scope.login = $scope.login? false : true;
        $scope.hideLogin = $scope.hideLogin? false : true;
     };
     $scope.closeLoginDiv = function () {
        $scope.login  = false;
        $scope.hideLogin = true;
     };
     $scope.isPassword = function () {
         if ($scope.passwordValidation === "123456789") {
            $scope.login  = false;
            $scope.hideLogin = true;
            
         } else  {
            alert("Wrong password. Try again!");
         };
     };
   });
 myApp.controller('catCtrl2', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/game-programming")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.books = response.data;
    });
 $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/category")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.categories = response.data;
    });
    $scope.login = false;
    $scope.hideLogin = true;
    $scope.showLoginDiv = function() {
       $scope.login = $scope.login? false : true;
       $scope.hideLogin = $scope.hideLogin? false : true;
    };
    $scope.closeLoginDiv = function () {
       $scope.login  = false;
       $scope.hideLogin = true;
    };
    $scope.isPassword = function () {
        if ($scope.passwordValidation === "123456789") {
           $scope.login  = false;
           $scope.hideLogin = true;
           
        } else  {
           alert("Wrong password. Try again!");
        };
    };
  });
```

as you can see, both controllers have same content, but i would like to make only one controller for different pages, any advice how i could make it? i tryed to set same controller in $routeProvider but its not working :(

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to set the same controller in $routeProvider and what error it threw?  That is what you are supposed to do in order to do what you're asking.

Comment: i tryed to do next: 
myApp.controller('catCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
   $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/" + $routeParams.name)
but when i did that only first page worked, others didnt worked, i got empty list of products

Comment: did you also change the controller in the `$routeProvider`.  If you pop open the console/network tab does it show any errors?

Comment: i did, let me check again but im sure i did that, i will check console

Comment: okay, i checked, nothing in console, when i click on other page just name of category changes, products are still the same

Comment: Looking at the code I would expect the products to stay the same if you are using the same controller because it makes the same `$http` requests.  If no error is being thrown then it sounds like you successfully used the same controller for both views.

Comment: Yeah but i want my products to change when choose other category, but they are always the same, i think my $http request is not good

Comment: I didn't notice it before, but you can't have spaces in your `.when('/category/Web development', {`.  It needs to be something like `.when('/category/Web_development', {`

Comment: Nah, nothing changed

Comment: @Aleksander That was just something else I spotted that will cause other issues for you down the road.  I think the real issue is not having any logic to determine which view you're on.  You could do something like this: `if ($location.url().indexOf('/category/Web_development') >= 0)`

Comment: I will try that, btw. thank you for your time :)

Comment: No problem, I sincerely enjoy helping the dev community

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach would be something like this:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/category/:category', {
    templateUrl: function (urlattr) {
        return '/category/' + urlattr.category + '.html';
    },
    controller: 'CategoryController',
    controllerAs: 'categoryCtrl'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/category/web_development'
  });
}]);
myApp.controller('CategoryController', ['$routeParams', '$http', function ($routeParams, $http) {
    var categoryCtrl = this;
  // Use $http based on $routeParams.category
}]);
```